# android appcompat v22 2 Global theme overrides toolbar theme for burger icon

Tags: android, toolbar, android-theme, android-appcompat

I'm using the support library AppCompat v7 22.2. My app uses a light theme that I've set up as follows

```
<style name="Theme.SM3Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/s3m_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/s3m_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/s3m_accent</item>
</style>
```

In my manifest I have

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SM3Theme"
```

I want my Toolbar to be themed dark so I get light colours on a dark background, like so

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sm3_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/s3m_primary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
android:gravity="center" >
```

And it almost works. I don't have the 10 reputation needed to post images but the burger icon for the DrawerLayout is always black in line with the Light theme of the global theme. The back arrow and the title text are light/white which is consistent with the theme specified in the Toolbar.

I've can't seem to get that to change. Worked fine with version 21 but then I didn't have to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar until I got the "IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features" errors.

Anybody know how to get this to work? Happening on both Lollipop and Jellybean 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in your app theme Theme.SM3Theme

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Widget.SM3Theme.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
```

Create style Widget.SM3Theme.DrawerArrowToggle as follows:

```
<style name="Widget.SM3Theme.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @ Ankur Bingo! I know I'm not supposed post "thanks" but really thanks, man

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong themes, you need to use these in your toolbar

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: I have tried that, and a number, of others but to no avail.

Comment: did you try copying what I wrote exactly? because there is an error in what you have in your themes

Comment: Yes, I checked and rechecked. I really want to fix this.It's consuming hours of my time I'd rather use improving app functionality than this. BTW could you explain why not using ThemeOverlay is wrong, please?

Comment: No you didn't do this exactly like I said because you have your theme as android:theme when it should be app:theme

Comment: Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V the two lines of code you provided into my tool bar XML including app:theme, over writing what I had, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to alter that color using the `colorControlNormal` attribute. Try defining a new style:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and use `android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"` over the Toolbar.

Looks like AppCompat's `ThemeOverlay`s set the `colorControlNormal` attribute to be `android:textColorPrimary`, which is definitely not what we are looking for, because it will stick to the main theme you have set - a light one, in your case.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but again it's not working. Frustrating! I've got to have something else wrong somewhere but can't see it . BTW it's "Theme.Appcompat" for dark and @android:color/white if anyone wants to try this. I found that, by setting different colors this way, it will change the color of the back arrows but not the burger icon!

Comment: Are you using your own burger icon or using the default? Did you provide the icon yourself?

Comment: @m vai Default burger icon.

Comment: What if you set colorControlNormal in your main theme? Does the burger icon reflect this change?

Comment: @m vai Yes, that  worked!!! The burger icon is now white. Except, now all my check boxes and radio buttons are white too so it's not really workable :-(